# Typescript: Get type of an instance's generic

Tags: typescript, generics

**The problem:**

Say I have a interface from a third party library that uses generics

```
interface SomeInterface<T> {
    ...
}
```

And in my code I have an instance that implements that interface

```
const someInstance; // type signature: SomeInterface<string>
```

Given this instance, how would I access the type of the generic type parameter T for that instance (in this example, how would I be able to extract the `string` type from `someInstance`)? I don't need it for runtime, I just need it so that I can define what type to expect as an argument in a function:

```
function someFunction(someArg: ???) {...}
```

Basically I want to be able to do this, which doesn't work:

```
function someFunction(someArg: typeof T in someInstance) {...}
```

**Specific use case:**

My specific use case here is that I'm using the `redux-act` and `redux-sagas` packages. Redux-act provides an action creator factory which produces an action creator with a type signature of `ActionCreator<P, M>`

```
// someActionCreator has type signature of ActionCreator<string, void>
const someActionCreator = createAction<string, number>(...);
```

When this action creator is called via `someActionCreator(payload: P, metadata: M)`, it produces an `Action<P, M>`.

```
// someAction has a type signature of Action<string, number>
const someAction = someActionCreator("foo", 1);
```

In redux sagas, I have access to the action creator instances (ie `someActionCreator`), where `P` and `M` have defined types, but I don't have access to the actions themselves. However, the handler functions expect the action as the argument, such as

```
function* someEffectHandler(action: Action<string, void>) {...}
```

Since Typescript knows what the types of `P` and `M` are on `someActionCreator`, I want to be able to access them inside the type declaration of `someEffectHandler`.
What I'm trying to avoid is having to write tons of boilerplate for every single action, when the action creator should be able to give me the typed parameters.

```
//Trying to avoid this
type SomeActionPayload = string;
type SomeActionMetadata = number;
export type SomeAction = Action<SomeActionPayload, SomeActionMetadata>;
export const someActionCreator = createAction<SomeActionPayload, SomeActionMetadata>(...);
```

Comment: Not always possible, but you can drill down to the property with type T and do `typeof` that property.

Comment: @unional Unfortunately, because the instance doesn't have a value for T yet (just what type it expects it to be), there is no property on the instance to call `typeof` on.

Answer (score 9):

```
type GetInnerType<S> = S extends SomeInterface<infer T> ? T : never
```

usage:

```
type InnerType = GetInnerType<typeof someInstance>
```

Comment: Is it possible to generic type of _any_ type? Like `S extends any<infer T>`

Comment: @fregante resolving T in that case is not useful because you don't know what it can be used for. You don't know if it is the type of - for example - a property or return or input so you can't do anything with it.

Answer (score 1):

You can play around a bit and you can get the generic arguments out from a generic type.

```
// Helper method, this will declare it returns a tuple of the two generic argument types, but at runtime it will just return an empty array. Used only to help with type inference.

function inferHelper<P, M>(creator: (p: P, m:M) => Action<P,M>) : [P, M]{
    return <any>[];
}
// Dummy variable, will be typed as [string, number] in your example, but will not actually hold anything at runtime
let helper = inferHelper(someActionCreator); // Dummy variable should not be used
// we get the type of the first tuple element, which we can then use 
type firstArg = typeof helper[0];
// and the second
type secondArg = typeof helper[1];
```

I am not 100% sure that this solution achieves your stated goal of having less boilerplate code but it does extract the generic arguments. One advantage is perhaps that if you refactor the original action you don't have to change any types, all types will be inferred correctly wherever you use firstArg and sec

Answer (score -1):

You can make the types work like below. Not sure if this is what you're looking for.

```
// define the function
function someFunction<U extends SomeInterface<T>>(someArg: T) {...}

// call the function
someFunction<typeof someInstance>(someArg) {
    // someArg will have type string
}
```